# What we have to check when upgrate jboss server version

Tags: jboss

I want to upgrade jboss server version from 4.2.0 to 4.2.3. What i need to look or see documents to do the upgradation? Please give me points i need to consider, documents to verify to upgrade any server version?
This information will be useful to upgrate any version? Currenlty i am doing for 4.2.0 to 4.2.3?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hm, seems that upgrading from 4.2.0 to 4.2.3 you can manage without any reading... The difference between these servers are just [bugs fixed](http://planet.jboss.org/post/jboss_4_2_3_released).

> This is the 3rd bug fixing release of the JBoss Application Server v4.2 series.

well, just deploy there your application, change configuration (the way you did for 4.2.0, if you did), and it should work.

Added: you will need to study some wikis, articles, APIs when you are going to migrate to JBoss 5.x or 6.x - it will take some time (I managed migrating from 4.2.3 to 6.0 for 1 week). Starting from 5.x they changed architecture of server a bit, folders where you put libraries (actually it was improved), there are deprecated APIs (e.g. in Hibernate), so you need to change API you use etc. But not in your current case, 4.2.0 -> 4.2.3 = that's easy :)